# 'expected expression before 'struct' ' and 'too few arguments to function' errors in C program

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, syntax-error, function-call

```
struct library{
int id;
int qty;
char name[50];
};

int SearchBookID(const struct library b[],int SearchID,int start,int end)
{

    if(start<end && b[start].id == SearchID)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d",b[start].name,b[start].id,b[start].qty);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        SearchBookID(b,SearchID,end,start++);
    }
}
void main()
{
    int choice;
    char ans;
    int SeID;
    printf("Welcome to the Library.\n");
    do
    {

        printf("Please choose an option:\n");
        printf("1.Insert a book\n");
        printf("2.Delete a book by ID\n");
        printf("3.Search a book by ID\n");
        printf("4.Search a book by name\n");
        printf("5.Display all books (sorted by name)\n");
        printf("6.Display all books (unsorted)\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch (choice){
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("please enter book ID:");
            scanf("%d",&SeID);
            SearchBookID(struct library b[],SeID,0,50);
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Choice. Please try again.\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("do you want to choose another option?(y/n)  ");
        scanf(" %c",&ans);
    }while(ans == 'y');
}
```

I keep getting these two errors and I don't understand why, especially the 'too few arguments' error. I tried to define the structure as global variable with 'typedef' but still the error persist  and when I add more arguments to the function it still says 'too few arguments'. Anybody can help.

Comment: Now and in the future, when you post a question about an error or warning message, include the entire error or warning in the question.

Comment: also: post the complete source, including headers. BTW: `main()` should return int.

Answer (score 3):

This call

```
SearchBookID(struct library b[],SeID,0,50);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is incorrect. Instead of supplying an expression as the first function argument you wrote a declaration.

Compare this record with the function call inside the function itself

```
SearchBookID(b,SearchID,end,start++);
```

Pay attention to that nowhere in the program you declared an array with the element type `struct library`.

Comment: Stated more generally - when calling a function and passing in a variable, you don't repeat the type of the variable. Just give the name.